# How to disallow other iPhones from sending me iMessage?

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I make it impossible for other people to send me an iMessage?

If they try to use iMessage, I would like their Apple device to force them to text instead.

I turned off iMessage in my phone's own settings.

Comment: That should be working if you disabled iMessage. Do you have other apple devices?

Answer (score 1):

If you've turned off iMessage on all your devices with your AppleID and are still facing issues you can turn off iMessage for your phone number on https://selfsolve.apple.com/deregister-imessage/